# What is Data Persistor?

Tags: magento2

What is Data Persistor? How and when it can be used?

I can see its usage in

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/Index.php
```

inside `execute()` method

```
$dataPersistor = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface::class);
$dataPersistor->clear('cms_page');
```

Comment: does my answer, answers or helps your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its just a class which stores data to the current user session. You can `set`, `get` and `clear` data from the session.

Have a look  at the `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistor` class `SessionManagerInterface` is used in every method.

You could use this to store temporary data to be used across the framework which don't need to be stored otherwise in the database.

[What are sessions?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science))